# cc and bcc not working for try to send mail using Web_API_v3

Tags: node.js, api, sendgrid

I'm try to send email with "cc" and "bcc" using the API Request
`POST https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send HTTP/1.1` .

I got an error like this

`{"errors":[{"message":"The to array is required for all personalization objects, and must have at least one email object with a valid email address.","field":"personalizations.1.to","help":"http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/errors.html#message.personalizations.to"},{"message":"The to array is required for all personalization objects, and must have at least one email object with a valid email address.","field":"personalizations.2.to"}]}`

using the data part like this

`--data '{"personalizations": [{"to": [{"email": "example@email.com"}]},{"cc": [{"email": "example@email.com"}]},{"bcc": [{"email": "example@email.com"}]}],"from": {"email": "example@email.com"},"subject": "Hello, World!","content": [{"type": "text/plain", "value": "Heya!"}]}'`

Comment: this belongs to sendgrid support not stackoverflow

Comment: I wanted to hide recipients from each other in bcc, but I found you can use the `to` parameter to send separate messages (so there's no need to hide recipients from each other). If that suits your case: With node client (`"@sendgrid/mail": "^7.7.0"`, currently), you can set the `isMultiple` parameter in the `send()` call, while using the regular `to` array: `await client.send(message, isMultiple);` with `message.to = [email1, email2]` and `isMultiple = true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is not correct for this use case. You are closing your personalizations object after the "to" object, when it should contain the `cc` and `bcc` objects as well.

[Here's an example](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Send/v3_Mail_Send/personalizations.html#-Sending-a-Single-Email-to-a-Single-Recipient-With-a-CC-and-a-BCC).

```
{
  "personalizations": [{
      "to": [{
          "email": "recipient1@example.com"
      }],
      "cc": [{
          "email": "recipient2@example.com"
      }],
      "bcc": [{
          "email": "recipient3@example.com"
      }]
  }]
}
```

You can put `subject` in a personalization as well, but not `from` or `content-type`.